# Chrome 65 Changes panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome 65 came with the long-awaited Changes panel, but I couldn't get it to work on a couple of sites. Are there any conditions/pre-requisites for this to work (like for example it will not work with WebpackDevServer-driven pages)?